# Regular expression java read from properties

Tags: java, regex, string, properties

I have a task with regular expressions in java and i have a question.

```
sentences = text.split();
```

How can i pass to () a regular expression from regexp.properties file

```
regexp.DECLARATIVE_SENTENCE = "\\.";
```

for example.

I could use a constant like

```
public static final String DECLARATIVE_SENTENCE  = "\\.";
```

and than make

```
sentences = text.split(DECLARATIVE_SENTENCE);
```

but i need to read the argument from properties file. How can i do that? With resource bundle for example?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to load the regex value from a properties file.

To do this you can use a class within Java called [Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html).

```
public Properties GetPropertiesFile(String location) throws IOException {
   Properties prop = new Properties();
   FileInputStream inputStream = null;

   try
   {
      inputStream = new FileInputStream(location);
      prop.load(inputStream);
   } finally {
      if (inputStream != null) {
         inputStream.close();
      }
   }

   return prop;
}
```

You may have to play with the `FileInputStream` and use the `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream` depending on you're case, but this should get you close.

Here's how you use the function above:

```
Properties prop = GetPropertiesFile("regexp.properties");
String regex = prop.getProperty("DECLARATIVE_SENTENCE");

String[] ret = str.split(regex);
```

You may have to change the properties file location depending on your configuration, and maybe even the `FileInputStream` if the property file is a resource).

Answer (score -2):

```
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(resourceBundleName);
rb.getString(DECLARATIVE_SENTENCE)
```